# Why my selector.select() get Hangs

Tags: java, nio

I'm writting a BASIC NIO programe in Java,

```
 ServerSocketChannel serverChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open(  );
 ServerSocket serverSocket = serverChannel.socket(  );
 Selector selector = Selector.open(  );
 serverSocket.bind (new InetSocketAddress (1234));
 serverChannel.configureBlocking (false);
 serverChannel.register (selector, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
```

When i Perform the following Operation

```
 int n = selector.select();
```

It never came out from this statement, i can specify the Timeout value, doing so every time the value of n is 0

Comment: It means nothing has happened to any of the sockets being selected on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the javadocs... it will only have n > 0 if a some OP was selected. This will happen in your example if a socket is accepted. Just do a telnet localhost 1234 and you will see it in action.

Comment: telnet 0 1234
Trying 0.0.0.0...
Connected to 0.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hi there!